# How find average of numbers(by input) and also count numbers

Tags: c#

I mean how to count and sum input numbers until receive "end".

thanks !
And also how to find out input is number or letter in c#?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        string inp;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Numbers ");
            inp = Console.ReadLine();
            int num= Convert.ToInt16(inp);
            sum = sum + num;
            n++;
        } while (too == "end");
        int average = sum / n;
        Console.WriteLine(" " + average);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh sorry yeah in *(inp)

Comment: Add them to the list and use LINQ for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a normal while loop and also add validation to check to integer input.

For the while loop you want to loop until the input is not equal to "end":

```
while(inp != "end")
```

For the validation, you can use `int.TryParse` method:

```
int num = 0;
if (int.TryParse(inp, out num)) { }
```

---

Here is a modified example of your code:

```
int n = 0;
int sum = 0;
string inp = null;
while(inp != "end")
{
    Console.Write("Numbers ");
    inp = Console.ReadLine();
    int num = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(inp, out num))
    {
        sum = sum + num;
        n++;
    }
}
int average = sum / n;
Console.WriteLine(" " + average);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you i'm beginner on c#, what does keyword "num" do?

Comment: @user43532: There is no keyword `num`, `num` is a local variable that is used to hold the parsed `int` value.

Comment: oh sorry, i mean "out". its my mistake.

Comment: `out` is used to specific that the parameter you supplied can effectively be changed by the function you supply it to. Which isn't normally true for non-reference type such as `int`. Its used in this instance to allow the `TryParse` function to effectively *return* 2 values, a `bool` as the actual return value (which determines if the parse was successful) and the `int` value that is the result you want. You can [read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
// A list to hold all of the numbers entered
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

// Will hold the inputted string
string input;

// This needs to be outside the loop so it's written once
Console.Write("Numbers: " + Environment.NewLine);

// Keep going until we say otherwise
while (true)
{
    // Get the input
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    // Will hold the outcome of parsing the input
    int number = -1;

    // Check to see if input was a valid number
    bool success = int.TryParse(input, out number);

    // If it was a valid number then remember it
    // If ANY invalid or textual input is detected then stop
    if (success)
        numbers.Add(number);
    else
        break;
}

// Write the count and average
Console.WriteLine("Count:" + numbers.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Average:" + numbers.Average());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Input:

> Numbers:
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

Output:

> Count: 5
>   Average: 3

The only thing here a little different to what you specified is ANY invalid or textual entry causes it to finish, not just typing the word "end", although that obviously works too.